# Change options menu during runtime - invalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, menu

I am creating a menu where one of the items is used the lock an object. When this item is clicked, the menu should be recreated with a button to unlock the item. I created two menus for this. This is working fine. I read that in Android version >= 11 the onPrepareOptionsMenu is no longer called when displaying the menu and I have to call invalidateOptionsMenu(). So I changed the build target (both in the Manifest and in properties) to 11 and ran the app on an AVD of 4.0.3. The program is still working fine, but I thought it shouldn't anymore, and I should check

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity3 extends Activity{

    boolean locked;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locked = false;
    }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu1, menu);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            menu.clear();
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

            if (locked) {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu2, menu);
            }
            else {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu1, menu);
            }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case R.id.Menu1:
          break;

          case R.id.Menu2 :
          break;

          case R.id.Menu3 :
          locked = !locked;
          break;

           }
        return true;
        }
}
```

So the Menu is still refreshed/recreated in 4.0.
Did I misunderstand something about the usage of invalidateOptionsMenu();?

Comment: I don't know how to report it, but even android developers isn 't clear enough about this. Check here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus?hl=en#ChangingTheMenu 
If you read just this, you will understand that invalidateOptionsMenu() will not call onCreateOptionsMenu() and that in Android >= 11 OnPrepareOptionsMenu() does not work every time you open the menu... but it does. WTHeck? Great question erdomester and great answer @justinmorris

Answer (score 36):

`invalidateOptionsMenu()` was added to give us the ability to force `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to be called again.  `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is still called every time you call the menu.

What you are trying to achieve above is a good example of when to use  `invalidateOptionsMenu()` but because of backwards compatibility you will need to do both:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        selectMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        selectMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}

private void selectMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    if (locked) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu2, menu);
    }
    else {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu1, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! This looks good! But I don't see what the invalidateOptionsMenu() does here. At first, onCreateOptionsMenu is called. If API >= 11, selectMenu() is called, but if API < 11 what happens? I haven't run the code (can't at the moment), but I don't why would the options menu open if API < 11.
Another thing: If on an item click, I call invalidateOptionsMenu() (when API >= 11), onPrepareOptionsMenu is called by system automatically, but it only inflates the menu if API < 11, so it does nothing, does it?

Comment: Using invalidateOptionsMenu() in your use case is nothing more than a micro performance improvement.  Ultimately its more efficient on newer devices to call invalidateOptionsMenu() only when "locked" changes.  Then 11+ devices will only inflate a new options menu when there is a reason to but older devices will re-inflate an options menu every time the user hits the menu button.  You could get the same performance enhancement, but backwards compatible, by using a boolean switch and checking it in onPrepareOptionsMenu() to see if you need to re-inflate the menu.

Comment: So basically I don't even have to call invalidateOptionsMenu(). It's just a safety method for devices with API > 11, right? And still, in your code the selectMenu is called only when API < 11, so if you call invalidateOptionsMenu() the menu will not be refreshed aka. lock will not changed to unlock.

Comment: Correct, you don't need to call invalidateOptionsMenu().. I was just showing you how you could.  In my code I only call selectMenu from onPrepareOptionsMenu() if the API < 11 because in my code if the API is higher I would have called invalidateOptionsMenu() and that would cause selectMenu to be called from onCreateOptionsMenu().

Comment: another option is to use one menu xml and have groups.  The visiblity of groups can be changed in the onPrepareOptionsMenu()