# How do I use setText do set text of existing EditText item?

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

**Edit: I'm an idiot, move on...**

The code and xml is below. I'm not getting any errors, but the text doesn't display. Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Code:

```
public boolean onPrepareMenuOptions ( Menu menu ) {
    EditText currency = (EditText) menu.findItem ( R.id.currency );
    currency.setText ( "test" );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
    getMenuInflater ().inflate ( R.menu.new_project, menu );
    return true;
}
```

XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/currency"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/currency_summary" />
```

Comment: have u called sethasoptionmenu(true) in onCreate?

Comment: Does it work when called in the `onCreate()` or `onResume()` methods?

Comment: I'm not calling sethasoptionmenu, but that only seems to apply to fragments? Haven't gotten to those yet. Learning one thing at a time.. :) Putting it in onCreate gives: "The method setHasOptionsMenu(boolean) is undefined for the type NewProjectActivity".

Comment: have you tried to add `return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);` not `return true` ?

Comment: Couldn't add to onCreate, "undefined for the type ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `onPrepareMenuOptions` is not being called. Here is what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu) says:

> On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
>   each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be
>   open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event
>   occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call
>   invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu().

You could solve this problem in two ways:

1) Method 1: Update the text at the time of `onCreateMenuOptions` (can update the XML file directly if you want)

2) Method 2: Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` somewhere in code, just before the menu is shown.

**Update**: I noticed a bug in your code, should be calling `super.onPrepareMenuOptions()`

```
public boolean onPrepareMenuOptions ( Menu menu ) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); // this is important
    EditText currency = (EditText) menu.findItem ( R.id.currency );
    currency.setText ( "test" );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
    getMenuInflater ().inflate ( R.menu.new_project, menu );
    return true;
}    `
```

Comment: You're right! I thought it was called automatically, for some reason.

Comment: Adding a call to "onPrepareMenuOptions" solves the problem. However for some reason I get a NullPointerException on the line "currency.setText ( "test" );". Eclipse doesn't complain.

Comment: what do you mean by adding a call? Can you update the code or maybe post a new question.. not sure which one is considered better..?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 EditText currency = (EditText) menu.findItem ( R.id.currency );
 SharedPreferences fill = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
 currency.setText ( fill.getString("string_name","String_Value" );
```

Comment: I solved the problem above using method 1 pointed out by Amulya Khare. However, now I'm getting a NullPointerException thrown by "currency.setText" instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179589/change-options-menu-during-runtime-invalidateoptionsmenu, follow this link it may help you...