# android app change menu on startup, at what stage?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

In my Java Android App's MainActivity I have a Toolbar on top (set via `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`) with a `youAreloggedIn` icon. On starting the app and before it shows or soon after, I want to make a remote connection, check if user is logged in to that remote server and change the icon to indicate that: a lock if not logged in (which is the default) or an opened-lock if user is logged in.

My question is in which callback I should place this code (network enquire and icon change). Right now I have the code at the end of `onCreateOptionsMenu()` after the menu is inflated.

Is there another `onXXX()` callback which is more suitable?

Apparently, `onStart()` is called before the menu is inflated! And so, I can't change icons in there before the menu in the toolbar is created!

Something like `onSteadyState()` perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu()), you can call it after the network fetch with can be called *asynchronously* in onstart()

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374955/404438)

Comment: Many Thanks. So, ```onStart()``` is the place and I must do this asynchronously via a callback. My network checks are already asynchronous, so I will make sure that they then call this. This answers my question. But I hoped I also got an answer as to why at the end of ```onStart()``` the menu is not drawn yet! Sure, asynchronicity. But...

Comment: Menus are created when OnCreateOptionMenu() is implicitly called at the end of onCreate(); so your menu should've been created even before onStart() ! 
Can you provide some code so I can better help you?

Comment: What I have is an ```androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar``` which in ```onCreate()``` is added using ```setSupportActionBar(toolbar);```. Then I overwrite ```public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); return true;}``` And that's it. The menu is created eventually. Problem is that when I try to change a menu-icon inside ```onStart()``` menu is still null. And so I am forced to do all network checks and subsequent icon-changes in ```OnCreateOptionMenu()```.